# Why won't PHP see the sqlite libraries when it runs a script?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to make something with PHP and sqlite. I've got both the sqlite3 and pdo_sqlite3 libraries loaded (according to php -m), the php.ini gets the libraries added, but I still get the fatal error that the function (whether it's sqlite_open() or sqlite_versioninfo()) isn't found. phpinfo() shows that both libraries are loaded. So why can't I use them?

Some info about my setup:

I'm running on debian, I'm running Apache2 and PHP 5.4.4-4. I can't remember how I installed PHP (apparently not through apt-get), but it's launched through Apache.

The output of `php -m`:

> root@ns:~# php -m [PHP Modules] bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype curl
>   date dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv imagick
>   json libxml mbstring mhash mysql mysqli openssl pcntl pcre PDO
>   pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML
>   soap sockets SPL sqlite3 ssh2 standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm
>   tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib
>
> [Zend Modules]

The exact error text is `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion() in [file] on line 14` and it occurs both through the command line and the webserver.

If I think of anything else to add, I'll add it here.

Comment: the fatal error comes from a script run via the command line, or via a webserver?

Comment: @rambocoder I updated my question. It occurs both through the command line and the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using functions from the [sqlite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) extension, but you enabled the separate [sqlite3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) extension.

and pdo_sqlite3 is only for pdo.

Comment: Well, this looks like the solution. I guess I'll have to install sqlite, I'm not interested in the OO stuff at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Or I'll have to suck it up and just use the sqlite3, it's installed and PECL tells me that sqlite's been superseded by PHP, while PHP says it's back to PECL. So yeah, sqlite3 looks like the better option.

Comment: consider pdo unless there's something in the sqlite3 extension that you really need that pdo doesnt let you get access to, because pdo is the standard in php and it works pretty good. the only exclusive thing i see in sqlite3 is busyTimeout() and loadExtension()

Answer (score 0):

If you are running php with php-fpm, and compiled the library after the php-fpm started, you should restart the php-fpm, then the new library will be effet.